# VM-Assign Load balancing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, cloud, load-balancing

i have following java code of active monitoring load balancer algorithm. algorithm selects the least loaded VM for request allocation. i have to add one conditon to this algorithm. if selected VM is used in exactly last iteration than it again search for least loaded VM. else request is allocated to that VM. HOW CAN I ADD THIS TO ALGORITHM.
[Flow of algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPcTT.jpg)
JAVA CODE: https://github.com/suhailgupta03/Cloud_Analyst_In_Progress/blob/master/src/cloudsim/ext/datacenter/ActiveVmLoadBalancer.java

```
package cloudsim.ext.datacenter;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import cloudsim.ext.Constants;
import cloudsim.ext.event.CloudSimEvent;
import cloudsim.ext.event.CloudSimEventListener;
import cloudsim.ext.event.CloudSimEvents;
import java.util.Set;


public class ActiveVmLoadBalancer extends VmLoadBalancer implements CloudSimEventListener {
    /** Holds the count current active allcoations on each VM */
    private Map<Integer, Integer> currentAllocationCounts;

    private Map<Integer, VirtualMachineState> vmStatesList;


    public ActiveVmLoadBalancer(DatacenterController dcb){
        dcb.addCloudSimEventListener(this);
        this.vmStatesList = dcb.getVmStatesList();
        this.currentAllocationCounts = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
    }

    /**
     * @return The VM id of a VM so that the number of active tasks on each VM is kept
     *          evenly distributed among the VMs.
     */
    @Override
    public int getNextAvailableVm(){
        int vmId = -1;

        //Find the vm with least number of allocations

        //If all available vms are not allocated, allocated the new ones
        if (currentAllocationCounts.size() < vmStatesList.size()){
            for (int availableVmId : vmStatesList.keySet()){
                if (!currentAllocationCounts.containsKey(availableVmId)){
                    vmId = availableVmId;
                    break;
                }               
            }
        } else {
            int currCount;
            int minCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (int thisVmId : currentAllocationCounts.keySet()){
                currCount = currentAllocationCounts.get(thisVmId);
                if (currCount < minCount){
                    minCount = currCount;
                    vmId = thisVmId;
                }
            }
        }

        allocatedVm(vmId);

        return vmId;

    }

    @Override
    public void cloudSimEventFired(CloudSimEvent e) {
        if (e.getId() == CloudSimEvents.EVENT_CLOUDLET_ALLOCATED_TO_VM){
            int vmId = (Integer) e.getParameter(Constants.PARAM_VM_ID);

            Integer currCount = currentAllocationCounts.remove(vmId);
            if (currCount == null){
                currCount = 1;
            } else {
                currCount++;
            }

            currentAllocationCounts.put(vmId, currCount);

        } else if (e.getId() == CloudSimEvents.EVENT_VM_FINISHED_CLOUDLET){
            int vmId = (Integer) e.getParameter(Constants.PARAM_VM_ID);
            Integer currCount = currentAllocationCounts.remove(vmId);
            if (currCount != null){
                currCount--;
                currentAllocationCounts.put(vmId, currCount);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged this as `c`, or did you just find the tag aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: no i tag it.. bcz its just need one do while loop in code.. but i get error in simulation.. just error in logic so..

Comment: You should make your question more concrete. You cannot just post your code and say "please take it and implement this modification for me". Instead, please explain what is your doubt exactly, what it is that you can't figure out. That way, you will surely get more help. Thanks.

Comment: i am going to implement this condition using do while loop. do {select least loaded} while(vmId == assignedVm).. but simulation (cloud Analyst) dosent shows any results

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. [Current Status of VM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloudsim/aKYKKu1lozA)

You can invoke getTotalUtilizationOfCpu method passing current Time and then you'll recover a double value represent the % of CPU Usage of Vm at that moment. Based on that you can compare the status of your VM with previous iterations. Getting this value you can solve your VM Status rules and schedule tasks.